# Ways to send (SMTP) email through ASP.net web applications

Tags: email, smtp, asp.net-2.0

Like there are many roads to Rome, there are also many ways to send an email from an ASP.NET application. When using just the SMTP protocol, which frameworks and libraries do exist that would allow sending emails from a web application?
I'm not interested in a single solution but would like a list of useful (or useless) alternatives. But only alternatives that use SMTP, with or without additional authentication and/or SSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `System.Net.Mail` namespace has all you need to send out e-mails from an ASP.NET application. Check the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) for details.

For further details and intros, see:

- [Scott Gu's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/16/432854.aspx)
- [A site specifically dedicated to System.Net.Mail](http://www.systemnetmail.com/)

There's a gazillion of other, freeware and commercial, libraries for sending mails (just [consult Google](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=asp.net+send+smtp+mail) or [google it with Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=asp.net+send+smtp+mail&go=&form=QBLH&filt=all)) - but typically, unless you have very specific / odd needs, `System.Net.Mail` components should be just fine, really.